# Different project settings for user Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, environment

How can I do different project settings for users in the same project. I have a project with some .properties file like email.properties which contains user-specific settings.I need something like user-specific enviroment settings, something like this: email..properties, and variable  contains in OS enviroment or, maybe, in project file

Comment: Is there anything wrong with each individual developer taking those .properties files and editing them to suit their personal environment needs?

Comment: They include in mercurial and some users may apply changes on it. Email properties is only one example, there are  some files with common project properties, another contains pathes

Comment: Add a template to mercurial under a different name and have the individual developers copy and fill out the template.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done this in some projects.  I create a [System Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to the path of the property file.  The path is outside of the project so the properties file is never committed.  But to help others who are running the project for the first time, I commit a template properties file with default options.

In intellij, I start the project with a different -D option than my coworkers do and the startup options don't get committed (because we don't commit the .idea folder).

Answer (score 0):

As a result a do the same: at first I created properties folder in propject root, add there file env.properties which contains current environment name (or user can add it as JVM start paramenter `-Denv=<env name>`. I add static class and method `Properties getProperty(String fileName)` which receive property file name as parameter and return all records in file as java.util.Properties.

```
public static Properties loadProperties(String fileName)
{
    Properties properties = null;
    if (propertiesMap.containsKey(fileName)) {
        properties = (Properties)properties.get(fileName);
    } else {
        String environment = getEnvironment();
        try {
            properties = (new PropertiesLoaderImpl()).LoadAllPropertiesForUtilAndEnv(environment, fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {}            
    }
    return properties;
}

private static String getEnvironment() {
    // Проверка на наличие параметра при запуске java-машины
    String environment = System.getProperty("env");
    if (environment == null) {
        try {
            // Попытка найти файл env.properties
            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("properties/env");
            environment = bundle.getString("env");
        } catch (MissingResourceException exception) {
            environment = "";
        }
    }
    return environment;
}
```

Property search implements that way:
1. look in ..proeprties;
2. if there is no suitable property, then look in .property;
3. else return empy.